# Symfony form design, entity design

Tags: php, jquery, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working on a small app with a survey syste. I've did most of the part but i'm stuck at generating the survey itself.
Based on the following requirements this is how my form should work:
Survey Manager Entity:

1. Define survey name - done
2. Define a scope of the survey - done
3. Define instructions on the survey - done
4. Adding questions to the survey -not done.
   All above are made in a single form that it is build by parsing the Entity to the form.

Now i need to add questions to the survey. The questions are stored in their own table called QuestionManager with a many to many association on a table where i define answers called AnswerManager.

The way that the survey form should work and i have no idea how to achieve this and that's why i came here asking for help.
The survey is based on chapters so first of all i should have a button to add a chapter then have a button to add questions to that chapter and after i'm done adding to that chapter move on to the next chapter ( again click on add chapter ) and continue ading questions.
The field to add a question should be a dropdown that means i can have an EntityType field no problem here, after selecting from the dropdown field the question a simple form should appear with all the assigned answers to that question and be able to modify them and this is the tricky part which again i'm not sure how to achieve it.

As a list how it should work:
 - Add chapter
 - Add Question - from dropdown and load the answers for it
 - Be able to modify answers to the selected question
 - After all the questions have been added to the survey it should be
    submitted and saved or returned with the errors
All i have so far as design and code: 
 - I know i should have one more table where i should store all the above
 - The form will be a nested one i think

Can you guys take some time and help me figure out how to do this maybe with a bare-bone example ideas, etc?

Answer (score 0):

I would use an Array for that task:

```
array(
  [chapter0] => array(
                      [question0] => 'Here comes your question to edit',
                      [question1] => 'There is the other question,
                      ......
                      ),
  [chapter1] => array(
                      ...... 
                     )

)
```

Store that to the database into an Array Collection or serialize it and store it then.

I hope this will give you an idea to point you in a different direction.